# Why there is a roundedIcon property in Android 7.1

Tags: android, material-design

[Android 7.1 api preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#circular-icons) mentions about a property called `android:roundedIcon` to use in an application tag. Android already supports rounded icons since they are only png's. When you make them rounded on a transparent background, well they are rounded.

Obviously Android is trying to uniform the launcher icons. Isn't it possible to round `android:icon` above api level 25? Or let the developer use api level qualifier like `mipmap-v25`. Why is it needed to add another property. What is the difference between this two? What does *"devices that support them"* means?

Why does Android make simple things complicated?

Comment: Can you please comment about why you downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the round icon will be launcher specific. Current information suggests that Google will bring this only to the Pixel Launcher, so e.g. Nexus devices won't use it by default.

On top of that, it opens the possibility for launchers to make it configurable should users prefer the old icon style.